# Where did Thanos go at the end of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Where is Thanos at the end of the *Avengers: Infinity War*...since it's apparently not Titan?

Answer (score 5):

It's his "whatever place" according to this interview. And it's not Titan.

> So, at the end of the movie, what is this planet that Thanos is on?
>
> Anthony Russo: Oh, the new planet?
>
> Yes. He seems very content.
>
> Joe Russo: It’s his whatever place that he goes.
>
> Is that his house?
>
> Anthony Russo: He’s like a holy warrior. 
>      Once he puts his armor down in that movie he becomes like a holy warrior 
>      and this is his resting place for him. 
>      He says in the film he’s just going to sit and watch the sunrise.
>
> Joe Russo: He accomplished his mission.
>
> So at that point he’s not anywhere weird or inside the Soul Stone or anything?
>
> Joe Russo: No, no.

[Link](https://uproxx.com/movies/russo-brothers-thanos-avengers-infinity-war/)

Comment: Here it seems Russo Brothers confimred , it happens on soul world, https://nerdist.com/infinity-war-soul-stone-world-russo-brothers-nerdist-news/

Comment: @ZaidSyedMMd The scene with Gamora immediately after the snap takes place inside the Soul Stone. The question, however, is asking where Thanos went after that, when he teleported away.

Comment: Didn't the Russo brothers clarify exactly what the name of the planet was that he settled down on?  "Titan2" sticks in my head but I dunno where I got that.